# Gradle build fails with cannot find symbol "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI"

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, java-7, xml-signature

I am using gradle to build my multi-module project.
In one of my class, i have the following code segment.

```
private XMLSignatureFactory factory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance(
            "DOM", new org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI());
```

But when i build this project using gradle, the compilation is getting failed with the following error message.

```
error: package org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom does not exist
private XMLSignatureFactory factory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", new org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI());
```

But i have already verified that the above class is from rt.jar of JRE.
I have tried with JDK 7 and 8.

What may be the root cause of the above issue?

Regards,
Mayuran

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem with you. And I solved by adding below configuration to build->maven-compiler-plugin.

```
<compilerArguments>
    <verbose />
    <bootclasspath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar;${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</bootclasspath>
</compilerArguments>
```

It seems like maven can't find rt.jar in higher jdk version(for me the version is  1.8), so we need to configure explicitly.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: even after too much time this issue was reported, this answer helped me to fix that.